Glacier Bay two handle bathroom faucet still leaks after catridge replacement
I have a Glacier Bay two-handle bathroom faucet. The hot tap leaks water very slowly around the base of the hot handle when either tap is turned on. After removing the handle, I can see that the leak is coming from the top of the cartridge.
I figured the cartridge was worn out so I bought a replacement cartridge and installed it. However, the new cartridge actually leaks worse than the old one. I'm wondering if it's not quite the right cartridge or did I do something wrong.
Here's a picture of the faucet with the handles removed:

And here is exactly where the leak is coming from when the taps are turned on:

And here are the old and new cartridges,


The new cartridge is Moen OEM part M0005, labelled as a replacement cartridge for Glacier Bay, Eurostream, and Danze. As you can see, they're similar but not identical. E.g. the old one has a washer at the bottom, while the new one has that metal part. But I they're very similar looking and I didn't see a variety of Glacier Bay replacement cartridges so I assumed this was the right part.
When I install the new cartridge and turn on the shut off valve, the cartridge lifts up about 1mm and water starts rapidly seeping out around it.
If you look closely at the side view you can see they're slightly different heights.
Did I buy the wrong replacement cartridge? If so, is there a different Glacier Bay bathroom faucet cartridge I can guy. Does anyone know the manufacturer part number?
Or is this faucet old enough that the cartridge design has changed and this can't be serviced anymore.
For the record, I did double check that the cartridge retention nut was on tight.
Thanks.

put some plumber grease on that o-ring

The O-ring around the cartridge? Would you expect that to stop a slow leak from the cartridge like this? I haven't tried that yet.

yes, that o-ring is leaking

Your faucet is worn or corroded inside where the O-ring is supposed to seal the cartridge to the faucet body.
You can try to use some fine emery cloth to clean the cartridge receptacle. However you are probably looking at purchasing a new faucet assembly.

Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this, and also added some plumber's grease as suggested in the comments above by Traveler. Had to crank the cartridge retaining nuts down pretty tight, and after that the leaks appear to be gone. I'll keep an eye on them and replace the whole faucet if they come back. After I realized I had bought the wrong replacement cartridge, I found the correct ones on Amazon. But they cost almost as much as a whole new faucet of the same make.

"The hot tap leaks water around the base..." Since it's not from the faucet, and it leaks, "when either tap is turned on," then the leak is inside the faucet, between the point where the hot and cold water mix and the outlet.
It appears it might be possible to remove the panel at the front; if so, look for a pipe or connection with a pinhole leak.
However, fixing such a leak may be difficult or unfeasible. If the water is acidic, and has corroded a pipe causing that leak, then after patching, it would soon leak elsewhere.
Perhaps the easiest and most cost-effective fix would be replacing the entire faucet.

Hi, sorry, I was unclear about the leak source. When I said base, I meant base of the handle. I've clarified that point and added an extra picture with a close-up showing the leak source. It's definitely around the top of the cartridge.
